# Maximum socket descriptor value

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, file-descriptor

What maximum value of socket descriptor, which I get using functions `socket()` and `accept()` on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Are you asking what the max value returned by these method/function calls is?  I'm curious to know how you plan to use this information?

Comment: I want to know this too so I can figure out whether it's a reasonable thing to do to look up an associated piece of data by using a SOCKET handle (or a SOCKET handle divided by X=4,8) as an array index. How big would the array need to be?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, sockets are not "small integers" like they are in Linux, they are opaque "handles".

So there's even less value in knowing some kind of maximum, it might be the same as the maximum *pointer* on the platform, for instance.

See [this documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value will usually be the same as the number of file descriptors simultaneously opened by that process.

However it's not AFAIK defined that way in any standard.

A socket descriptor is an `int`, so the *theoretical* value is `INT_MAX`, but that would make calls like `select` somewhat hard to implement, hence why they're just sequentially allocated.